# Hide information sent by Exim4

Tags: exim

I am working with RabbitMQ + PHP to receive send email requests from my application.
When RabbitMQ receives the request, PHP uses PHPMailer to connect to the Exim server and send the email.

However, I saw the original message and noticed that the IP of the PHP machine that made the request to Exim (so far OK), the name of the VM that the PHP VM (that's not OK), and the server's Exim version (Definitely not OK).

```
Received: from <GOOGLE-PUBLIC-IP>.bc.googleusercontent.com 
([MY-VM-PUBLIC-IP] helo=MY-RABBITMQ-PHP-VM-NAME) 
by my-exim-server.example.com with esmtp (Exim 4.90_1) 
(envelope-from <noreply@example.com>)
```

How can I hide the PHP VM name and Exim version (even the Exim name) in the email that is sent to the client?

Answer (score 1):

As default, hostname is used for helo field. You can [change that using the `primary_hostname` directive](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html).

For version, that's the `smtp_banner` option.

If any of those is problematic for security reasons, you should probably revise your security practices.

Answer (score 1):

To change the received header, Edit (or set)  the [`received_header_text`](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.90/doc/html/spec_html/ch-main_configuration.html) setting of the exim server instance.

But first consider why you want to hide this information.

If the server has an embarrassing or controversial name, rename it before it leaks out some other way... If any of the other information is a security risk you have already lost.

When you hit email delivery problems, or the server suddenly starts emitting batches of 100000 emails. having that information will be very useful.